# Delete cookie on another site

Tags: javascript, security, cookies

Is it possible to delete a cookie on one site when being redirected to that site from another site? Or is that impossible due to security restrictions?

Site A has a login form that submits to and logs in as Site B. When the user logs out from Site B after using Site A's login form, Site B forwards them back to Site A. Is there any way for Site A to delete a cookie on Site B without access to Site B's backend/code?

Comment: Thankfully it is not possible for one site to modify another site's cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not if site A and site B are on different domains. There is a `domain attribute` that can be set in the `Set-Cookie` header, but this must be either an exact or partial match for the current domain. By partial match I mean that it is possible for `foo.example.com` to set a cookie for `example.com` but not for `ample.com`.

Source [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265) (HTTP State Management Mechanism):

> When the user agent "receives a cookie" from a request-uri...

> If the canonicalized request-host does not domain-match the
> domain-attribute:

> **Ignore the cookie entirely**

Bear in mind that a cookie deletion is really *receiving a cookie* with an expiry date in the past so that is why the above still applies.

Site B would have to implement a mechanism to allow this to happen.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not allowed for - as you guessed - security reasons.

Take a look here for further details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: This is correct. The cookie would have to be deleted on Site B's end when processing the log-out.